# .NET Mutex on windows platform: What happens to them after I'm done?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mutex

I've got a simple .NET program, which checks to see if another instance has been started:

```
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false,"MyMutexName");
    if (!mutex.WaitOne(1))
        return;

    try{
    //do stuff
    }
    catch{ //exceptions}
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

My question is, what exactly happens to the mutex if you forget to release it when the program ends? Is it visible in some windows control panel component? Where does it live?

Comment: Named mutexes are normally only used for coordinating cross-process communication, which isn't what your example is showing at all.

Comment: @Steven: Using mutexes for this is a really good use. Far better than trying to detect a previous window or process name or something.

Comment: I updated my question, as you're doing two semi-related things in your code: 1) Using a named mutex to detect the existence of a previous instance of your application 2) Synchronizing across processes with that mutex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a named mutex so it is visible and can be opened in other processes.  Windows uses a simple reference count on the handle.  If you don't Dispose() it explicitly yourself then the finalizer will close the handle for you.  If your program bombs hard and never executes the finalizer then Windows will do it when it cleans up the resources used by your program.

That will automatically decrement the reference count.  If that counts down to zero (no other processes have a handle open on it) then the kernel object is released.

In other words: you don't have a problem no matter how badly things turn out.  The actual mutant object lives in the kernel memory pool.  You can see it with the SysInternals' WinObj tool.

Comment: Right, this is what I said initially about the handle itself. The complication here is that, if another process gets a handle to your named mutex, and then you shut down a thread after acquiring ownership, the mutex is abandoned. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: Also, Mutex.Dispose() does not release it. Need to call ReleaseMutex() explicitly, otherwise the new owner will receive AbandonedMutexException.

Answer (score 4):

Mutexes are OS-level handles. They'll get closed when your process does (if you don't close them sooner, that is.)

*edit*

Ok, I clearly misunderstood the example *and* the question. If you're just trying to detect whether another instance exists, you'd create a named mutex (or similar object) and simply check for its existence without ever locking on it.

The call to `WaitOne` locks on it, taking ownership, while `ReleaseMutex` gets rid of it (so long as there are no additional calls to `WaitOne`). If you end the thread without releasing the mutex fully, it does leave the object in a bad state, as explained in the text Micah quotes.

I took your question as being about whether you close the *handle* before the process completes, which is another thing entirely.

*additional*

At the SDK [API][1] level, you can call `CreateMutex` with the expectation of failing when a mutex of the same name has already been created. In .NET (well, in 4.0, at least), there's a [constructor][2] that fills a `createdNew` bool.

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(VS.85).aspx CreateMutex

[2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k(v=VS.90).aspx Mutex

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex.aspx)

> If a thread terminates while owning a
>   mutex, the mutex is said to be
>   abandoned. The state of the mutex is
>   set to signaled and the next waiting
>   thread gets ownership. If no one owns
>   the mutex, the state of the mutex is
>   signaled. Beginning in version 2.0 of
>   the .NET Framework, an
>   AbandonedMutexException is thrown in
>   the next thread that acquires the
>   mutex. Prior to version 2.0 of the
>   .NET Framework, no exception was
>   thrown.
>
> **Caution**
>
> An abandoned mutex often indicates a
>   serious error in the code. When a
>   thread exits without releasing the
>   mutex, the data structures protected
>   by the mutex might not be in a
>   consistent state. The next thread to
>   request ownership of the mutex can
>   handle this exception and proceed, if
>   the integrity of the data structures
>   can be verified.
>
> In the case of a system-wide mutex, an
>   abandoned mutex might indicate that an
>   application has been terminated
>   abruptly (for example, by using
>   Windows Task Manager).

Comment: To clarify, what makes a mutex "system-wide" is that more than one process has a handle to it. Otherwise, when the process closes, it takes the mutex with it.